# Convert to JSON from SELECT Query in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a select query output as below

Both NULL or BLANK may come.
[image]

I am trying to achieve below output

```
[
    {
        "COL1_VALUE": "TEST_TEST1",
        "COL2_VALUE": "COL2_TEST1",
        "COL3_VALUE": "11/17/2022",
        "COL4_VALUE": "ABCD",
        "COL5_VALUE": null,
        "COL6_VALUE": null,
        "COL7_VALUE": "123456",
        "COL8_VALUE": 678
    },
    {
        "COL1_VALUE": "TEST_TEST1",
        "COL2_VALUE": "COL2_TEST2",
        "COL3_VALUE": "11/8/2022",
        "COL4_VALUE": "XYD",
        "COL5_VALUE": null,
        "COL6_VALUE": null,
        "COL7_VALUE": "123456",
        "COL8_VALUE": 678
    },

    {
        "COL1_VALUE": "TEST_TEST2",
        "COL2_VALUE": "COL2_TEST6",
        "COL3_VALUE": "11/15/2022",
        "COL4_VALUE": "RTY",
        "COL5_VALUE": "RYU",
        "COL6_VALUE": "GHJ",
        "COL7_VALUE": "67856",
        "COL8_VALUE": 123
    }
    
]
```

I wrote code like below

```
SELECT TO_JSON(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('Values', ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('COL1_VALUE', COL1_VALUE ,'COL2_VALUE', COL2_VALUE, 'COL3_VALUE', COL3_VALUE, 'COL4_VALUE', COL4_VALUE, 'COL5_VALUE', COL5_VALUE, 'COL6_VALUE', COL6_VALUE, 'COL7_VALUE', COL7_VALUE, 'COL8_VALUE', COL8_VALUE)))) FROM TABLENAME
```

However, unable to get desired output.

Any suggestions ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest object_construct inside of array_agg

```
select array_agg(object_construct_keep_null(*)) COL1
from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.NATION;
```

Remember that Snowflake is going to limit this to 16mb on the single-field output.

Output:

```
[
    {
        "N_COMMENT": " haggle. carefully final deposits detect slyly agai",
        "N_NAME": "ALGERIA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 0,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 0
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "al foxes promise slyly according to the regular accounts. bold requests alon",
        "N_NAME": "ARGENTINA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 1,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 1
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "y alongside of the pending deposits. carefully special packages are about the ironic forges. slyly special ",
        "N_NAME": "BRAZIL",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 2,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 1
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "eas hang ironic, silent packages. slyly regular packages are furiously over the tithes. fluffily bold",
        "N_NAME": "CANADA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 3,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 1
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "y above the carefully unusual theodolites. final dugouts are quickly across the furiously regular d",
        "N_NAME": "EGYPT",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 4,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 4
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "ven packages wake quickly. regu",
        "N_NAME": "ETHIOPIA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 5,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 0
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "refully final requests. regular, ironi",
        "N_NAME": "FRANCE",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 6,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 3
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "l platelets. regular accounts x-ray: unusual, regular acco",
        "N_NAME": "GERMANY",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 7,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 3
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "ss excuses cajole slyly across the packages. deposits print aroun",
        "N_NAME": "INDIA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 8,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 2
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": " slyly express asymptotes. regular deposits haggle slyly. carefully ironic hockey players sleep blithely. carefull",
        "N_NAME": "INDONESIA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 9,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 2
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "efully alongside of the slyly final dependencies. ",
        "N_NAME": "IRAN",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 10,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 4
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "nic deposits boost atop the quickly final requests? quickly regula",
        "N_NAME": "IRAQ",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 11,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 4
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "ously. final, express gifts cajole a",
        "N_NAME": "JAPAN",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 12,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 2
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "ic deposits are blithely about the carefully regular pa",
        "N_NAME": "JORDAN",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 13,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 4
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": " pending excuses haggle furiously deposits. pending, express pinto beans wake fluffily past t",
        "N_NAME": "KENYA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 14,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 0
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "rns. blithely bold courts among the closely regular packages use furiously bold platelets?",
        "N_NAME": "MOROCCO",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 15,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 0
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "s. ironic, unusual asymptotes wake blithely r",
        "N_NAME": "MOZAMBIQUE",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 16,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 0
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "platelets. blithely pending dependencies use fluffily across the even pinto beans. carefully silent accoun",
        "N_NAME": "PERU",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 17,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 1
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "c dependencies. furiously express notornis sleep slyly regular accounts. ideas sleep. depos",
        "N_NAME": "CHINA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 18,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 2
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "ular asymptotes are about the furious multipliers. express dependencies nag above the ironically ironic account",
        "N_NAME": "ROMANIA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 19,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 3
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "ts. silent requests haggle. closely express packages sleep across the blithely",
        "N_NAME": "SAUDI ARABIA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 20,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 4
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "hely enticingly express accounts. even, final ",
        "N_NAME": "VIETNAM",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 21,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 2
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": " requests against the platelets use never according to the quickly regular pint",
        "N_NAME": "RUSSIA",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 22,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 3
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "eans boost carefully special requests. accounts are. carefull",
        "N_NAME": "UNITED KINGDOM",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 23,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 3
    },
    {
        "N_COMMENT": "y final packages. slow foxes cajole quickly. quickly silent platelets breach ironic accounts. unusual pinto be",
        "N_NAME": "UNITED STATES",
        "N_NATIONKEY": 24,
        "N_REGIONKEY": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank, you,  so i did this                                                                                                                                     ``` select array_agg(object_construct(*)) COL1
from TABLENAME ``` However, blank values are not shown, that means, if the cell value as Blank, the column does not come. "COL5_VALUE": null, should come.

Comment: Both NULL or 'NULL' or BLANK or SPACE etc may come in data set, it should take them as well.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can use `object_construct_keep_null` instead of `object_construct`. Both of them should preserve blank values (empty strings) but you will need the keep null option to, well, keep the nulls :)

Comment: Thanks much, will it work with BLANK , NON-String NULL, SPACE as well?

Comment: Both of them should work with blank strings or spaces. For database NULL it will need to be `object_construct_keep_null`.

Comment: 16 mb  is the max value, do we have the snowflake note on this ?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#characteristics-of-a-variant